# Скажите можно ли работать в Intellij Idea с maven через консоль?

Tags: intellij-idea, maven

любая команда с maven - начинается с mvn. например, mvn compile. Почему когда я пытаюсь сделать это в консоли IDea он пишет, что mvn не является внутренней или внешней командой. И еще как указать путь к классам? или в чем может быть причина такой фигни
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно установить Maven и добавить его в путь своей ОС.
[подробно](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/)

Comment: так я вроде все переменные добавил и когда в командной строке пишу mvn -version он мне выдает инфу, что все хорошо. или это не показатель? а если я через View maven буду работать это аналогично терминалу?

Comment: @ШаховГлеб а не пробовали перезагрузить IDEA. По идее если в простой консоле `cmd` у вас работает `mvn` то и в IDEA должно работать

Comment: спасибо, сработало. а еще вопрос я внедрял maven уже в текущий проект, и мои текущие классы он не видит, пришлось ручками перемещать все в папку src/java после чего после запуска он мне выводил какую то ошибку конфигурации и что то связанное с модулем, в чем может быть причина? и это ладно у меня один класс был, а если проект большой, тогда как мне моим классам указать путь, чтобы maven видел их

Comment: Так сложно сказать, создайте новый вопрос и укажите что за ошибки выходят. Думаю так будет легче